# Grails GORM and MYSQL cascade delete problem

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, mysql-error-1451

I have a table User that has many child tables defined in User class under the static hasMany
grails.

I have no problem when doing User.get(3).delete() in grails. It automatically delete that user and all its child table rows.
But when I want to perform the same operation in MySQL workbench. I get Error thrown by MySQL:

```
ERROR 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_db`.`search_stat`, CONSTRAINT `FK7A3CFFB6E64DB41` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
SQL Statement:
DELETE FROM `test_db`.`user` WHERE `id`='3'
```

I dont know what is the problem here with MySQL.

Comment: Check the definition of the table in MySQL. Do the foreign keys have "ON DELETE CASCADE" set, or is GORM/Hibernate doing the cascade in code behind the scenes?

Comment: I checked that in MYSQL workbench but under the Foreing Keys tab it does not show any foreign keys. Foreing Key Names and Reference Table tabs under that are blank. When I click on the blank, it automatically creates fk_user_1 and click the next tab, a drop down shows all the tables in the db for me to choose one as the referenced table. But I think something is wrong and I should not need to recreate the foreign keys. I tried to that delete commanind in the mysql command line version I get the same error thrown.

Comment: On the other hand the Grails GORM documentation clearly says the belongsTo automatically creates the cascade on delete/update behaviour. So this behaviour should have gone into db schema when GORM  created tables in MySQL db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you read about the "ON DELETE CASCADE" in the documentation? I haven't found it [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.2.1.2%20One-to-many). The poster of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374591/grails-multiple-belongsto-of-same-class-with-cascading-deletion) had to manually add this as well to get the desired behaviour.

If grails is really supposed to add this, have you tried deleting the DB and having it re-created by grails (at least in development environment)? Maybe the current schema was generated before you added the belongsTo or something?

Also check out [this Blog post about GORM Gotchas regarding hasMany and belongsTo.](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/)

Comment: http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html it clearly says: The default cascading behaviour is to cascade saves and updates, but not deletes unless a belongsTo is also specified.

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't say that this is "implemented" in SQL using "ON DELETE CASCADE", does it?. Maybe it's just grails functionality to cascade the delete using separate SQL statements.